# How can I use have before and after conjunction?

Tags: conjunctions, have

I am confused where should I use `have` after a conjuction if it has already used before it for the same noun. For example, I want to combine following sentences:

> I have played tennis. I have studied English.

Which is correct, where if since I use 'have' before a conjunction should I use it again?

- I have played tennis and have studied English.
- I have played tennis and studied English.

Answer (score 2):

In a short sentence like your first example, it's perfectly acceptable to leave out the second *have* (but please note that it's English with a capital E).

In  a more complex sentence like your second one, the meaning is clearer if you repeat *have.*

Comment: For complex sentences like my second example, is it also adviced to use semicolon before the first `and` since the second sentences have its own `and`?

Comment: No, I wouldn't advise a semicolon. You could use a comma there if you want.